# 1 Watt Audio Amplifier Using BJT

Tags: amplifier, design, circuit-design

I am trying to design a audio amplifier circuit but I do now know where to start. The only requirement given to us is for it to be a 1 watt amplifier. We have decided to use a 9v DC battery as source. I searched in google about the designs but I do not know how it becomes a 1 watt amplifier. I do have a background about the Voltage/Current gain and DC biasing I just need a hint what to do first.

EDIT: my load will be an 8 ohm speaker.

EDIT: I know the question is too broad. That's why I am also getting a hard time dealing with this thing. My professor only taught us how to solve BJT and FET circuits and gave us project like this.

Comment: Knowing you need to deliver 1W to a load, with 9V supply to start with, decide what output voltage level you want (6V peak-to-peak?). From here you can first find what output current you will need to provide 1W to the load.  Then check the nominal current which a 9V can provide (~150mA if I remember correctly). I would also probably use a totem-pole push-pull stage for the output.

Comment: IF you have no idea, the best learning tool is to understand how the recommended circuits work in Audio Amp IC's http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4889.pdf or look at primitive designs http://cdn-7.sci-toys.com/scitoys/scitoys/computers/solderless/small_1_watt_audio_amplifier.jpg

Comment: I searched the totem-pole push-pull stage you said. I'll try to study it. But I dont understand the output voltage you are talking about. Sorry I am a bad student. :(

Comment: I will study the pdf that you gave me Mr. Tony Stewart. But I browse something regarding the picture you commented. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/calculating-the-power-of-a-simple-amplifier

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm384.pdf  This IC shows internal  schematic.  totem-pole means current buffer for each polarity with overlap near zero using gain on front end with negative feedback to reduce error. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm384.pdf

Comment: Ching yes the "primitive " single Darlington also puts DC across the coil which is OK for low power but not very efficient and will pull tiny cone to one side. YOu can use an Op Amp to drive totem-pole with feedback too for simple design. Input DC ref is V+/2 so output must be AC coupled.  two 9V batteries allows DC couple.

Comment: For AC (like audio), power is defined as (V_peak)^2/(2R), so for 1W of power you need a peak voltage swing of 4V.  Also, more generally, P = V^2/R = I^2R, with V and I being the root-mean-square voltage and current at the load.  So, for an 8Ohm speaker, for 1W of power, you need a minimum r-m-s voltage of 2.82V (4V peak) and minimum r-m-s current of 353mA (500mA at peak).  A 9V battery will not last very long @ 350mA : for normal lifespan keep a 9V battery at ~30mA average current.

Comment: This IC thing is really cool. lol I'll try to learn from these things. I do not have any idea about this pull push things. May I ask. Does having more voltage gain will make my amplifier better?

Comment: @jbord39 How can I make the current at 30mA when the minimum current that I need is 500mA peak?

Comment: @ChingdGreat: That is a very good question ... I think the standard 9V battery will not work for you, unless you only need it to work for a very short time.

Comment: @jbord39 This is only a project so maybe I just can use a power supply to test run it. I learned something from this post. Thanks jbord39 and Tony Stewart   . I'll be back when I finished studying the push pull thing.

Comment: @ChingdGreat: Consider using the TDA8551. It's a 1W bridge tied load amplifier designed for what you are looking at, and it has been widely used and is pretty cheap. (Unless you actually want to design something discrete.)

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/audio-ic/speaker-amplifier-class-ab-class-d-product.page#p2627=Class-AB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and consider your thoughts about a \$1W\$ design. But quite frankly, the \$9V\$ source just isn't going to cut it. The reason is that assuming perfect efficiency and no headroom required for the circuit itself, the speaker requires \$V_{peak} = \sqrt{2\cdot P\cdot R}\$. In your case, this works out to \$V_{peak} = 4V\$. This is above *and* below the ground reference your speaker requires. So you need \$\pm 4V\$. Of course, you say you want to use \$9V\$. But this leaves only \$500mV\$ from each rail and I just don't believe you can readily consider that. So a traditional design would require you to give up on the \$9V\$ battery. (And in any case, you will want some kind of ground reference -- there are nice ICs for this, but you'll need something.)

You do have an alternative if you are absolutely stuck on the idea of using a \$9V\$ source. You can go to a bridge-tied load configuration. In effect, this is *two* amplifiers sourcing from the same battery but with one of them \$180^{\circ}\$ out of phase with the other one. The speaker is then tied between the two amplifier outputs. This would get you there. But it greatly complicates your design. If you want to see one of these, take a look at the [TDA8551](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiy2rf6oNHOAhUY22MKHcKACdEQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nxp.com%2Fdocuments%2Fdata_sheet%2FTDA8551_T.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGBCP4ZUOqLWO_Q7GdkiVpXUZJohw&sig2=Gu1MYLO_E3JeEaSTzANzzA) that I mentioned in an earlier comment to you. That is a BTL amplifier. But I don't think you want to go there. Looks like you are trying to get through a design of some kind (with only a tiny subset of the necessary specifications to do it.)

So this means you have to give up on the \$9V\$ power supply and accept something different. For now, let's assume you can accept \$\pm 6V\$ rails, with ground, and go from there. (Otherwise, I can't offer you much. No time to go around trying to explain a full BTL here.)

Let's assume you don't want horrible cross-over complications, but that you want a simple output stage, too. That means two BJTs with a pair of diodes to help spread apart the base voltages. That *block* looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYMPpK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Through those diodes, you will need a *waterfall* of current (shown as the drive current), which the output transistors can tap into. This current magnitude needs to be enough to drive the transistor bases. Since the peak \$I_c = \frac{4V}{8\Omega} = 500mA\$, and if we assume we can keep the BJTs out of saturation, then we can reasonably plan a gain of \$\beta=50\$ and estimate a maximum \$I_b = \frac{500mA}{50} = 10mA\$. We'll need a little extra available, though. Just in case. So let's set this up for \$15mA\$. A current mirror is handy. So let's add one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXi2MF.png)</sup>

(I'm ignoring temperature issues everywhere. And other effects. Just keeping this very, very simple.)

This current mirror allows me to set up a current flow from the \$+6V\$ rail down to the \$-6V\$ rail. Roughly speaking, I set up a current of about \$I_{drive} = \frac{+6V - 800mV - \left(-6V\right)}{680\Omega} \approx 16.5mA\$. Which is fine.

Now, we have to drive the thing. And now I have a serious issue. You didn't say what your source looked like, at all. I have no idea what you need for gain, no idea what loading is allowed on the input, and frankly nothing else about it. I'm clueless.

So I'm going to borrow a page from the other answer you got and just cheat. I'm going to use an opamp. Normally, though, that is not what you do. You will have a pre-amplifier that is designed for your input source, then you will have some perhaps variable gain, then you will drive the CTRL line I have above with a specialized circuit for that. (Possible Miller compensation for BJTs, too.) Then the above output stage. Then negative feedback of some kind is necessary.

(None of this takes into account that your speaker is a complex impedance and not a resistor, that some operator might short out the wires leading to the speaker, and ... well... oh, who cares? You didn't care about any of that, so neither do I.)

So let's just paste on an opamp to give you a fixed gain of 10 and to drive that CTRL line. I won't even bother with a separate current sink BJT. Instead, the opamp will need to be able to sink up to the full \$16.5mA\$ supplied by the current source as well as any PNP BJT base current that may also be required. So let's say at least able to sink \$30mA\$. If you don't like that, you can add a BJT to further lighten the load. I won't specify the opamp. But it will need to be able to get within about \$1V\$ of the bottom rail and perhaps within \$2.4V\$ of the top rail (because of those two diodes adding another \$1.4V\$.)

So here is the new circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKmxn9.png)</sup>

That should be able to reach about \$\pm 4V\$ on the output. There is still a lot to improve. But it gets the basic idea across. The opamp adjusts its output, sinking current while doing that. The current source sources current for \$Q_1\$ for the positive half of the cycle, leaving the opamp to sink the rest. Then \$Q_1\$ shuts off and \$Q_2\$ takes over for the negative half of the cycle and the opamp now has to sink not only the current source current but also any base current required for \$Q_2\$. That's why I said you need one that can sink up to the over-estimated \$10mA\$ base current of \$Q_2\$ plus the \$16.5mA\$ of the current source, or \$30mA\$ or better. (The opamp won't need to source, as that is what the current mirror is doing.) Also, keep in mind the output requirements for the opamp (within \$1V\$ of the negative rail and within \$2.4V\$ of the positive rail.)

Lots more needs to be discussed if you intend to actually make one of these and have it work reasonably well. I didn't care in the least about the wasted current during cross-over, where in this design it's very likely that both BJTs will be conducting a fair amount of current when the speaker drive voltage is near ground. And, I suspect, using the opamp is *cheating*. If so, there is lots more design work ahead for a discrete amplifier capable of \$1W\$ output and doing that safely into a speaker or some oaf shorting the speaker output leads, while allowing a nice volume control, plus supporting some one or two different specified kinds of input sources.

Comment: This is very good explanation. A step by step one although I don't know some of the terms you mentioned. But this will greatly help. I will try to simulate and consider the circuit you gave. Thank you!

Comment: May I ask a dumb question? Where did you get the 800mV in the Idrive Formula? @jonk

Comment: @ChingdGreat: That's an estimated Vbe for the current mirror BJT called Q4. It's running 'hot' so I know it will be more than 700mV. I don't think it really will be 800mV, to be honest. But I just rounded up and called it good.

Comment: @ChingdGreat: If you want, tinker with the 680 ohm resistor and make it larger (reduce the current.) The amplifier will probably run less "hot" that way. You may be able to get away with over 3k ohm for it.

Comment: Also, study Wilson current mirrors, as well. The one I used will experience a fair degree of variation from the Early effect. But I didn't care to do better, here.